# bullet list within texttt

Tags: formatting, lists, typewriter

I wish to insert a bullet list inside `\texttt{}` as part of the original reproduction. Is there a way to do this? When the list is copied directly from the original text, the rendering inside `\texttt{}` converts it to what I presume is an ASCII or Unicode conversion. A MWE is given below. In the MWE, I wish to replace the `<bullet>` with a suitable syntax to emulate the bullet point from the reproduced text.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\texttt{

<bullet> item 1
<bullet> item 2
....

}\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would imagine it suffices to use `\ttfamily \begin{itemize} \item ... \item ... \end{itemize}` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another `enumitem` approach, but automatic switching to `\ttfamily` using `before={\ttfamily}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{itemtt}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[itemtt,1]{label={\textbullet},before={\ttfamily}}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemtt}
  \item This is in typewriter font
  \item This is in typewriter font again
  \item \itshape\textrm{This is explicitly written in another font}
  \item And typewriter again, but with italics
\end{itemtt}

And this is in normal font


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

something like this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
\item item1
\item item2
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are not usefull, sorry it is my base tex file.